# wordpress ajax php function dont execute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

This is the first time I do the ajax and I must confess that I am confused. What I want to do is to take the value of 3 Select html to make a request to my database that'll get me a score according to the desired choice. The purpose of using ajax is that I do not want the submit button and I want that when the value of one of my select changes only choose my result in my database changes according to the new value. So the hen I change a value in my select I call a javascript that takes values ​​from my select and pass ajax to my function.php which then makes a request with the values ​​of my Selects function and then returns the result of my request.

Sorry for my English, this language is not my first language.

Now my code look like that:

javascript:

```
function showWidth($) {
  // get the value of my 3 html select
  var width1 = document.getElementById('width1').value;
  var width2 = document.getElementById('width2').value;
  var width3 = document.getElementById('width3').value;

  if (width1!="aucun" && width2!="aucun" && width3!="aucun") {
    $.ajax({
      ObjectName.ajaxurl,
      data: {
        action:'script_handle',
        width01 : width1,
        width02 : width2,
        width03 : width3
      },
      success:function(data) {
        // This outputs the result of the ajax request
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

PHP (in function.php):

```
function widthcalculate(){
    if( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
      $width1 = $_REQUEST['width01'];
      $width2 = $_REQUEST['width02'];
      $width3 = $_REQUEST['width03'];
      // Let's take the data that was sent and do something with it
      global $wpdb;
      $where = "'".$width1."' AND camber = '".$width2."' AND handrim = '".$width3."'";
      $sql = $wpdb->get_results(
       "SELECT result FROM mc_widthCalculatorResult WHERE wheel = ".$where.""
      );
      foreach ($sql as $element) {
        echo $element->result;
      }
      echo $result;
      //print_r($_REQUEST);
    }
    die();
  }
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_script_handle', 'widthcalculate' ); // Hook for the WordPress Dashboard.
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_script_handle_nopriv', 'widthcalculate' ); // Hook for the user facing side of the site.

  function register_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'script-handle', $path_to_javascript_file, $dependencies, 'version', $in_footer = true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-handle' );

    wp_localize_script( 'script-handle', 'ObjectName', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ), 'parameter' => $whatever_you_want_to_pass ) );
  }

  add_action( 'enqueue_scripts', 'register_scripts' );
```

Comment: where did you get those action names from they are non standard, are they definitely called?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tie your wp_enqueue_script and wp_localize_script to the proper WordPress hook before this function is processed.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', "FUNCTION_NAME");
```

FUNCTION_NAME would be the name of a function that contains just wp_enqueue_script and wp_localize_script.

Your wp_localize_script needs to have the same slug as your wp_enqueue_script.

Here's a boilerplate I keep around for doing AJAX in WordPress: https://gist.github.com/theantichris/6600226

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, there are many things unexplained and wrong.

1. You load scripts like this using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` filter. Note: not using an absolute path that could change, passing last two params correctly:

   ```
   function bones4_enqueue_scripts() {
       wp_enqueue_script('widthcalculator', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/widthCalculator.js', 'jquery', false, true);
   }

   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bones4_enqueue_scripts');
   ```
2. Your ajax script should be separate, not in functions.php, and it should not be in an action hook, it is bad practice to put it functions.php and the request won't get handled as it stands anyway.
3. You are sending an ajax request to a totally different script (`wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`)
4. What are `wp_ajax_nopriv_widthcalculate` and `wp_ajax_widthcalculate` filters - did you make those names up? When does Wordpress call them?
5. You are mixing camelcase, noncamelcase, hyphenated, and underscore naming conventions - why? Keep it consistent.
6. You are passing the path of a script with `wp_localize_script` but then not using it in the javascript and using an absolute path instead. At the very least you could ajax to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` but I'm not sure if that path is correct, if you are posting to a php file in your theme directory you should pass the path of that directory to javascript through something like `wp_localize_script` or trivially through something custom.
7. As I said you should make a separate ajax script you post requests to, inside it but not in any action hook you should have the `if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {` stuff.
8. You haven't explained what the intention of your script is so I cannot advise on better solutions, only what looks wrong in the existing code.

See how it goes from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I do the ajax and I must confess that I am confused. What I want to do is to take the value of 3 Select html to make a request to my database that'll get me a score according to the desired choice. The purpose of using ajax is that I do not want the submit button and I want that when the value of one of my select changes only choose my result in my database changes according to the new value. So the hen I change a value in my select I call a javascript that takes values ​​from my select and pass ajax to my function.php which then makes a request with the values ​​of my Selects function and then returns the result of my request.

Sorry for my English, this language is not my first language.

Now my code look like that:

javascript:

```
function showWidth($) {
  // get the value of my 3 html select
  var width1 = document.getElementById('width1').value;
  var width2 = document.getElementById('width2').value;
  var width3 = document.getElementById('width3').value;

  if (width1!="aucun" && width2!="aucun" && width3!="aucun") {
    $.ajax({
      ObjectName.ajaxurl,
      data: {
        action:'script_handle',
        width01 : width1,
        width02 : width2,
        width03 : width3
      },
      success:function(data) {
        // This outputs the result of the ajax request
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

PHP (in function.php):

```
function widthcalculate(){
    if( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
      $width1 = $_REQUEST['width01'];
      $width2 = $_REQUEST['width02'];
      $width3 = $_REQUEST['width03'];
      // Let's take the data that was sent and do something with it
      global $wpdb;
      $where = "'".$width1."' AND camber = '".$width2."' AND handrim = '".$width3."'";
      $sql = $wpdb->get_results(
       "SELECT result FROM mc_widthCalculatorResult WHERE wheel = ".$where.""
      );
      foreach ($sql as $element) {
        echo $element->result;
      }
      echo $result;
      //print_r($_REQUEST);
    }
    die();
  }
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_script_handle', 'widthcalculate' ); // Hook for the WordPress Dashboard.
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_script_handle_nopriv', 'widthcalculate' ); // Hook for the user facing side of the site.

  function register_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'script-handle', $path_to_javascript_file, $dependencies, 'version', $in_footer = true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-handle' );

    wp_localize_script( 'script-handle', 'ObjectName', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ), 'parameter' => $whatever_you_want_to_pass ) );
  }

  add_action( 'enqueue_scripts', 'register_scripts' );
```